# MySQL Conditional Select

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I've been trying all night to get the following query to work:

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND if(24hr = 'yes') user.last_mail >= DATE_SUB (user.last_mail INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Basically, I have 3 tables, containing username (`wine_users`), subscriptions (`wine_subscriptions`) and User Settings(`user_settings`)

What I WANT is to select users who have EITHER selected NO in us.24hr OR have selected YES in us.24hr (stored as an ENUM 'yes' 'no' in us.24hr) AND have NOT received an e-mail in the last 24 hours (this is stored as a TIMESTAMP in the user.lastmail)

Any help would stop me from tearing out my own brain through my left nostril! :)

Thanks :)

Seb

---

Wow! You guys are great! :) Tried all of the suggestions, but they all return the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INTERVAL 1 DAY))) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 8

I'm guessing it's got something to do with the DATE_SUB command not liking the TIMESTAMP format of the user.last_mail field... Could that be correct, and if so how do I handle this?

For clarity, the script is part of a page which gets fired by chron every hour which I've done for me & a few friends.
 It checks Tesco Wines for the availability of their "mystery wine pack" (because web design is always better with cheap wine!)
 If it is available (which only happens once a week or so) it e-mails anybody from the users database who EITHER has 24hr set to no (ie it e-mails them every hour while the product is available) OR has 24hr set to YES and hasn't received an e-mail in the last 24 hours
 (hence the last_mail field, which records the TIMESTAMP when the last e-mail was sent)

Really appreciate the responses!

Seb :)

Comment: I'd like you to group what you want. Is the AND NOT part associating before the OR part?

Answer (score 0):

See if this does the trick.

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND ( (24hr = 'yes' AND user.last_mail >= DATE_SUB (user.last_mail INTERVAL 1 DAY)) OR 24hr='no')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your question that 1 of the following 2 conditions must be met:

A.   users who have selected NO in us.24hr

B.   users who have selected YES in us.24hr AND have NOT received an e-mail in the last 24 hours

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND (
     user.receive_mail = 'no'
 OR (user.24hr = 'yes'
AND  DATE_SUB(user.last_mail interval 1 day) > user.last_Mail)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Union if I haven't read your question wrong:

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND if(24hr = 'yes') user.last_mail >= DATE_SUB (user.last_mail INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 UNION ALL
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
  FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND 24hr = 'No'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might be looking for this:

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND (
  (24hr = 'yes' AND user.last_mail >= DATE_SUB (user.last_mail, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  OR 24hr = 'no'
)
```

But I'd recommend you restate it using `JOIN`, like:

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users AS user
JOIN (wine_user_settings AS us, wine_subscriptions AS sub)
ON (us.id = user.id AND us.id = sub.user_id)
WHERE sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND (
  (24hr = 'yes' AND user.last_mail >= DATE_SUB (user.last_mail, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  OR 24hr = 'no'
)
```

Not that I can test this.

Comment: I used your second query, with a slight modification (the DATE_SUB (user.last_mail INTERVAL 1 DAY) needed a comma between user.last_mail and INTERVAL to make it work) Thanks everybody! :)

Comment: Cool, glad it worked, thanks for testing it and pointing out the edit I needed to make.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OR`:

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND (24hr = 'no' OR
     (24hr = 'yes' AND user.last_mail < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
```

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND 24hr = 'yes'
AND user.last_mail < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION ALL

SELECT user.username, user.email, user.id, user.last_mail, us.24hr
FROM wine_users user, wine_subscriptions sub, wine_user_settings us
WHERE user.id = sub.user_id
AND us.id = user.id
AND sub.wine1 = 'yes'
AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'
AND 24hr = 'no'
```

You sometimes find `UNION ALL` is more efficient though, even if it is more typing, as the database engine can find a more optimal execution plan.

Comment: You may notice that in the above SQL it uses "NOW()" instead of "user.last_mail" as the first parameter to "DATE_SUB"; Also, there is a comma after the first parameter. Perhaps these resolve the error that you mentioned in your second message?

Answer (score 0):

`user.last_mail >= DATE_SUB (user.last_mail INTERVAL 1 DAY)` can never be `False` !

I think you need to use function `NOW()` and some parenthesis with `OR`:

```
SELECT user.username
     , user.email
     , user.id
     , user.last_mail
     , us.24hr
FROM wine_users AS user
    JOIN wine_subscriptions AS sub
        ON user.id = sub.user_id
    JOIN wine_user_settings AS us
        ON us.id = user.id
WHERE sub.wine1 = 'yes'
  AND user.receive_mail = 'yes'           --- not sure if this line is needed
                                          --- what does `receive_mail` stand for?
  AND ( user.24hr = 'no'
      OR user.last_mail < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
      OR user.last_mail IS NULL
      )
```